# DataGrid.SelectedItems not recongnised

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, bindinglist

I am using a datagrid to display data from a database, I need to get the selected row, but when i use DataGrid.SelectedItem, it does not recognize the property SelectedItem.Does any one know what the reason might be?
I use bindinglist to bind the data to the grid.

```
    private void delete_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (selectAll == true)
        {
            ThisAddIn.sourceContext.removeAll();
        }
        else
        {                
            var grid = sender as DataGrid;
            var selected = grid.SelectedItems;

            foreach (var item in selected)
            {
                ThisAddIn.sourceContext.removeEntity ((Source)item);
            }                
        }           
    }
```

```
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableEvtCode}" 
        Name="SourceDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="10,40,10,10" IsReadOnly="True"
```

Comment: Need to define `ThisAddIn.sourceContect`. If this is your **DataGrid**, then show how you populate it with data.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error.

Comment: But your code is SelectedItems not SelectedItem.  Why not just get the DataContext of the button.  I think the syntax is ((Button)sender).DataContext.

Comment: I dont need DataContext of the button. The strange thing is that no matter where i try to call this property on DataGrid, it still says this definition does not exist. I have imported all the required references.

Comment: Does it make any difference to know that my DataGrid is of type window? public partial class DataGrid : Window

Answer (score 0):

[SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) is part of the [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

However, if nothing is selected, then you run into issues.

Does this help?

```
      var selected = grid.SelectedItems;
      if (selected != null)
      {
        foreach (var item in selected)
        {
            ThisAddIn.sourceContext.removeEntity ((Source)item);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but not the answer to my problem.